# Update change date for a file

Tags: files

I have managed to update the access and modified time of a file:

```
Access: 2003-06-03 14:45:00.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2003-06-03 14:45:00.000000000 +0300
Change: 2015-07-20 08:03:15.301534192 +0300
```

How can I do the same for the change time?
Using only touch will update all time-stamps to current time, but how can I update all to a custom time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man touch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/touch.1.html):

```
-d, --date=STRING
      parse STRING and use it instead of current time
-t STAMP
      use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
DATE STRING
   The  --date=STRING  is  a mostly free format human readable date string
   such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29  16:21:42"  or
   even  "next  Thursday".   A  date  string  may contain items indicating
   calendar date, time of day, time zone,  day  of  week,  relative  time,
   relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of
   the day.  The date  string  format  is  more  complex  than  is  easily
   documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Ok, so I did `touch -d '11 Nov 1992 16:16' 'path/to/file.jpg'` and only access and modify dates were updated, `Change` date stays the same. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes. `touch` can't and doesn't change ctime. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36021/how-can-i-change-change-date-of-file.

Comment: Well, that was the question and... that's the answer. Thanks.